# Injecting derived classes

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

I have a problem using ValueInjecter for derived classes:

```
public class A
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static void main()
{
  var b = new B()
  {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "Test!",
    Age = 47
  };

  var a = new A();

  a.InjectFrom(b);

}
```

Injecter does not seem to copy the properties of the derived class.

I then tried to use the Clone convention and debugged the different calls to the methods, but I could not even see calls for the properties of the derived class. Only the properties directly on class A were called.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
  Andreas Kroll

Comment: Well you can start by showing how you have written your `InjectFrom` method.

Comment: so the problem is that `a.Age` is not set ?

Comment: Since I did not write the InjectFrom method, I cannot show you. You do know that we are talking about ValueInjecter???

Comment: @Omu, the problem is that Age is copied, but the rest (Id, Name) is not. That is what I am wondering about. If I check which properties are "considered" by using the Clone sample, I only get a call with Age as property.

Comment: Age can't possibly be copied because a is of type A which doesn't have `Age` property, only Id and Name should be copied in your example